# If an integer $n$ is coprime to $6$, then prove that $n^2$ leaves remainder 1 on division by 24

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, divisibility, congruences

> If an integer $n$  is coprime to $6$, then prove that $n^2$ leaves remainder 1 on division by 24

I know that $n$ can be written as $6k+1$ and $6k+5$, but how to proceed?

Comment: i would square $$6k+1$$ and $$6k+5$$

Comment: You are more than halfway there with that observation.  Now... for each of the two cases compute $n^2$ and group as much as you can into terms which are divisible by $24$ and terms which are not.  $(6k+1)^2=36k^2+12k+1=24k^2+12(k^2+k)+1$.  Is $24k^2$ divisible by $24$?  Is $12(k^2+k)$ divisible by $24$?  (*Is $k^2+k$ divisible by $2$?*)  Do so similarly for $6k+5$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\implies n$ is of the form $6m\pm1$ where $m$ is any integer

Now $(6m\pm1)^2=24m^2+24\cdot\dfrac{m(m\pm1)}2+1$

as $m(m\pm1)$ are even being products of two consecutive integers.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\gcd(n,6) = 1$. We want $n^{2} = 24q + 1$ for some integer $q$. Note that it is equivalent to
$n^{2}-1 = (n-1)(n+1) = 24q$.
If $n = 6k+1$ for some integer $k$,
then
$(n-1)(n+1) = 36k^{2} + 12k = 24q$,
that is $k(3k+1) = 2q$.
Note that $k, 3k+1$ cannot be both odd. Then
we find $q = k(3k+1)/2$.

Likewise, if $n = 6k+5$ for some integer $k$,
then we are led to consider
$(k+1)(3k+2) = 2q$.
Again $k+1, 3k+2$ cannot be both odd,
so taking $q := (k+1)(3k+2)/2$ suffices.